# SQL query to get one-to-one mapping from a cartesian result

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, they dont have any relation but I need to transpose the rows if the rateType matches meaning rateId=1 from tbl1 can match with only one routeId but with same rateType, if rateType does not match then no need to fetch that result. I tried with inner join but not sure how to transpose result basis rateType matches.

```
select *
from
(select 1 as rateId, 'COST' as rateType from dual
 union
 select 2 as rateId, 'COST' as rateType from dual
 union
 select 3 as rateId, 'COST' as rateType from dual
 ) as tbl1
 inner join
 (
 select 11 as routeId, 'COST' as rateType from dual
 union
 select 12 as routeId, 'COST' as rateType from dual
 union
 select 13 as routeId, 'COST' as rateType from dual
 ) as tbl2
 on tbl1.rateType=tbl2.rateType
```

Result:

[image: Current Result]

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "transpose". For example, for rateId=1, why would you choose routeId=11 and not 12 or 13 ? They all have same rateType.

Comment: MySql v8 it is. Transpose meaning I want to do a one-to-one mapping between tbl1 and tbl2 if rateType matches, it does not matter whether rateId=1 is mapped with rateId 11,12,13 it could match any one but the next rateId=2 should not pick the same. Basically as I have two tables, I want to have a 4 column result where each id is uniquely mapped with id from other table provided rateType matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
with tbl1 (rateId, rateType) as (
  values 
    row(1, 'COST'), 
    row(2, 'COST'), 
    row(3, 'COST')
),
t1 as (
  select *, row_number() over() as rownum from tbl1
),
tbl2 (routeId, rateType) as (
  values 
    row(11, 'COST'), 
    row(12, 'COST'), 
    row(13, 'COST')
),
t2 as (
  select *, row_number() over() as rownum from tbl2
)
select rateId, rateType, routeId, rateType
from t1 inner join t2 using (rateType, rownum);
```

Result:

```
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
| rateId | rateType | routeId | rateType |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
|      1 | COST     |      11 | COST     |
|      2 | COST     |      12 | COST     |
|      3 | COST     |      13 | COST     |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/_FVAGB1s

---

**This is not intended to be a full solution for all cases.**

It's only a proof of concept to support the test case you provided.

If you have other cases, then it's up to you to adapt the solution to your other cases.

Comment: This would not fetch expected result if rowId=2 rateType is changed to something like "Amt" and rowId=13 rate type is changed to "Rev". It will only map rateId=1 with rateId=11 but it is expected to also fetch rateId=3 with rateId=12. https://dbfiddle.uk/iSBqLba0

Comment: Then, add `PARTITION BY rateType` to each window function.